# Javascript / Jquery script terminated by timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

So as a python guy I am experimenting with JS and Jquery. I wrote this small script to fold \ unfold a menu bar on a html page using Jquery slide. I believe this should work fine, however all it does is freezing my browser for around 10 secs after which in the console I get "script terminated by timeout". Anyone can point me in the right direction?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var Clicked = false; 
    while (true) {
    if (Clicked) {
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#menu").slideDown();
            $("button").replaceWith("<button type=\"button\">&#8593;</button>");
            Clicked = false;  
        });
     } else {
         $("button").click(function(){
             $("#menu").slideUp();
             $("button").replaceWith("<button type=\"button\">&#8595;</button>");
             Clicked = true;  
         });
     }
    }
});
```

Comment: The infinite `while` loop blocks all other browser execution. Remove the loop, and let the browser wait for clicks.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is due to the `while()` loop. In JS this is a synchronous operation which blocks all other threads (including, importantly, the UI renderer) which causes the browser to hang. This is why you see the alert stating that the operation has been terminated.

A better approach to this is to just have a single event handler which toggles the state of `#menu` and the text in the `button` which is clicked. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).html(function(i, h) {
      return h === '↑' ? '↓' : '↑';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">&#8595;</button>
<div id="menu">
  Menu...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks a lot more convenient

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is infinite. It keeps going to an `else` section and attaching `onClick` events to the button. I think you can simplify your code by eliminating unnecessary loop, `Clicked` variable and using only one `onClick` event handler to toggle menu.

I also changed `replaceWith` method with jQuery's [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which just takes HTML code as a parameter and puts it inside of your button depending on it's visibility.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
        var thisButton = $(this);
        if (thisButton.is(':visible')) {
            thisButton.html('&#8593;');
        } else {
            thisButton.html('&#8595;');
        }
    });
});
```