# Problem with infinite loop when manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I'm learning about DOM manipulation and, to practice, I'm trying to get the first 100 Twitter users who have twitted about [#Javascript](https://twitter.com/hashtag/javascript?src=hash&lang=es) (see link). As, for now, Twitter doesn't allow you to use `console.log()` function in the browser console, I have managed to show any string visually in the HTML, in this case, under the search textbox.

This is my "custom" `console.log()`

```
function consoleLog(data) {
    var searchTextBox = document.querySelector("#doc > div.topbar.js-topbar > div > div > div > div > div");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var innerText = document.createTextNode(data);
    p.appendChild(innerText);
    searchTextBox.appendChild(p);
}
```

For getting the usernames, I keep scrolling the page every 4 seconds and looking for usernames until I have 100 or more of them in my `usernames` variable.

```
var scrollPage = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}, 4000);

var usernames = [];
while (true) {    // <------ PROBLEM
    if (usernames.length < 100) {
        consoleLog("Getting usernames again");
        usernames = getUsernames();
    }
    else {
        consoleLog("We have ENOUGH usernames. BREAK");
        clearInterval(scrollPage);
        printUsernames();
        break;
    }
}

function printUsernames() {
    for(var user of usernames) {
        consoleLog(user);
    }
}

function getUsernames() {
    var results = [];
    var usernameNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("username u-dir u-textTruncate");

    var username = usernameNodes[0].textContent;
    for(var node of usernameNodes) {
        results.push(node.textContent);
    }

    return results.filter(isUnique);
}

function isUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

The problem is that the `while` loop enters in infinte loop and I don't know why. I think the logic of the code is correct. In fact, if I first copy and paste all the declared functions to the browser console, then start the `scrollPage` interval and, lastly, start the while loop, it works well. The problem comes when I copy and paste all the code at one time in the browser console. It is like the executions of the interval and the while loop conflict in some way. But I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have while conditioned like this:

```
var usernames = [];
// This will automatically end when length is greater or equall 100
// no need to break
while (usernames.length < 100) {
  consoleLog("Getting usernames again");
  usernames = getUsernames();
}
consoleLog("We have ENOUGH usernames.");
clearInterval(scrollPage);
printUsernames();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this neither work. But just now I was reading about the `while` loop "[...]In JS this is a synchronous operation which blocks all other threads (including, importantly, the UI renderer) which causes the browser to hang.[...]" from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275672/javascript-jquery-script-terminated-by-timeout). So, now I know the problem. And need to think another way to achieve my task.